# Spring boot Error :The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2

I am starting in spring boot but facing this issue of tls version. I have tried everything including changing the java.security file below i am posting the code of my application and complete error message if anyone can help me.

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
```

}
**This is my main class i have created the spring starter project in STS4.**

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDB;encrypt = false
spring.datasource.username=sheraz
spring.datasource.password=sheraz123

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

**this is my appliation.properties file**

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.5
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**This is my pom.xml file**

I have tried a lot of thing but still getting the error the error is:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:a195cbc5-abbc-4005-b48b-3295c3a64aaa
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3937) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1950) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3456) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2919) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1787) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1229) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:972) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:894) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1839) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
... 49 common frames omitted

[2m2023-04-16T14:14:54.561+05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:a195cbc5-abbc-4005-b48b-3295c3a64aaa
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3937) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1950) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3456) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2919) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1787) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1229) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:972) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:894) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1510) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1425) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1839) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11.jar:na]
... 49 common frames omitted

[2m2023-04-16T14:14:54.570+05:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m11492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[2m2023-04-16T14:14:54.571+05:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m11492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[2m2023-04-16T14:14:54.578+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-04-16T14:14:54.619+05:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m11492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-04-16T14:14:54.656+05:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m11492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
at

I have tried almost every method mentioned in google and also use ChatGpt for help but nothing helped i have been trying to solve it from 2 days. Hope i get the answer now.

Comment: Your server code is at least 10 years out of date. Fix that.

Comment: The problem is not on the Java side, it is on the SQL Server side. You're either using a SQL Server version so old it doesn't supports TLS v1.2 or v1.3, or it is not enabled.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am using sql server 2014

Comment: See the article linked in the duplicate. It also applies to SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @user207421 how can i do that?